# orderby not working on wordpress

Tags: sql-order-by

I trying to order by this values by a custom field (motor)  and this is not working. Can you help me? I use acf to create the custom field. And when I do a var_dump it doesn't recognize the order by the parameter.

```
    $args='';
    $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'grupoelectrogeno',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => '100',
    'meta_query' => array(
    array(
      'key'     => 'potencia_continua',
      'value'   => $postpotencia,
      'compare' => 'like'
    ),
    array(
      'key'     => 'motor',
      'value'   => $postmotor,
      'compare' => 'like'
    ),
     array(
      'key'     => 'version',
      'value'   => $postversion,
      'compare' => 'like'
    ),
     array(
      'key'     => 'gama',
      'value'   => 'industrial',
      'compare' => 'like'
    ),
     'orderby' => 'motor',
     'order'=>'desc',
    ), 
    );
```